# NSDate Predicate throws 'Unable to parse the format string' error

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I'm trying to use a predicate in my Core Data app. I'm using them throughout the app without any issue apart from this one:

```
NSPredicate *matchDatePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY matches.matchDate < %@", datePlusOne];
```

This throws the following error:
    'Unable to parse the format string "ANY matches.matchDate < %@"'

In a different view controller, the following works:

```
NSPredicate *matchDatePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY matchDate < %@", self.match.matchDate];
```

the datePlusOne is an NSDate property, as is self.match.matchDate.  I've tried various versions of the format string, using >, >=, =, == etc and get the same error every time.

Am I missing something really obvious here??

EDIT:  This is the Core Data entities that are being queried.  The predicate is searching from MatchStarts to Matches:

[image]

Comment: Just a wild guess: "matches" is a reserved word in a predicate format string - could that create a parsing error?

Comment: Yes!  Thank you!  I hadn't realised about the reserved words.  I fixed this by using '#matches.matchDate', as demonstrated in the docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html

Answer (score 1):

both predicates are different as seems one contains `matches.matchDate` while other is only `matchDate`. check if its the problem.

**EDIT:** for ANY  to work either matches has to be to-many relationship or matchDate has to be to-many relationship.
if both are to-one relations then you cannot use ANY.

Comment: The one that works is used on a Core Data entity, the one that doesn't is querying an entities relationship to another entity.  This should still work though shouldn't it?

Comment: See my edit for a screenshot of the Core Data entities.  It is a to-many relationship.

Comment: no, you don't have to-many relationship,see again.
Each MatchStarts object have one match(matches) and each matches has one matchDate.

Comment: you might be confusing with to-many relationship(inverse) of matchStarts

Comment: I tried removing the ANY word, but still no joy.  See Monolo's comment for the answer.  But I would have to have removed the ANY word to make it work anyway, so thanks for pointing that out.